# How to catch HTML image load timeout with plain javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

The question might be answered many times on the web across different forums, but I really couldn't find the exact answer of mine.

I'm pretty new to javascript and just playing with HTML & Javascripts. Want to write a simple script which will allow my HTML to load an img tag upto particular timeout and if it couldn't it will show an alert box. I found some answers of using setTimeout() using jQuery, but want to write it with a plain js.

So far what I've tried is: Catching the onLoad event of img and set a flag there. Side by side start a timer by setTimeout() with my given timeout value. And if the timeout expires and the flag inside onLoad() has not changed from it's initial value then I'm done.

```
<img id="img1" src="URL_HERE" onload="imgLoaded()" />

var isLoaded = 0;
function imgLoaded() {
    isLoaded = 1;
}

function qWinLoaded() {
    setTimeout(function checkImgLoad() {
        if (!isLoaded){
            document.getElementById("img1").src = "";
            alert("Failed to fetch given image within time!!");
        }
    },
    3000);
}

window.onload = qWinLoaded;
```

But with this above piece of code I have started the timer on window load. How do I start this timer once the html img tag actually start downloading the picture?

Comment: What is your use case for such a feature and what higher level problem are trying to solve?

Comment: @FabianLauer Well I'm thinking about catching the onLoad event of img and set a flag there. Side by side start a timer by setTimeout() with my given timeout value. And if the timeout expires and the flag inside onLoad() has not changed from it's initial value then I'm done. But here how do I stop loading the on going image?

Comment: @charlietfl There is no use case in my mind. This thing just came to my mind while doing some basic operation with javascript and html.

Comment: Well if the url that is passed to image tag isn't image file the error event will trigger quickly. Don't see why you would need a timeout

Comment: @charlietfl Yes true, this is code is for learning purpose not for solving any professional software issue.

Comment: idea doesn't really make sense. There are lots of resources on web and this site for `"image preload"`